# Get the maximum summation of 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

There is a 2D array. `int[][] arr= {{1,3,4,1},{5,7,8,9},{6,1,2,1}}` . I want to get summation of each columns and get the maximum number. Finally it should be returned `{5,7,8,9}` . Because it has the maximum summation. I have mentioned i tried code below and it not return correct value. Help me to solve this

Comment: Why should it return `5,7,8,9`? That is neither a column nor a max number.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee `5,7,8,9` summation is the highest. it summation is 29. that is why i want to return `{5,7,8,9}`

Comment: But that is a row and not a column.

Comment: shouldn't it be `{6,7,8,9}` here because there is a 6 in the first column?

Comment: i=k should be k=i.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee you are correct it is Row. It is  my mistake

Comment: If you [edit] your question to reflect that, you have a better chance at answers which help you...

Answer (score 3):

Your k is supposed to track the index with the greatest sum. So when you are resetting max you need to say `k=i`. You said `i=k` by mistake. Changing it makes your program run as desired.

EDIT: There was once code in the original question, to which this solution referred.

Comment: :-) Explanation WITHOUT code. What a refreshing change, compared to the other answers.

Comment: I added however just a touch of code formatting, hopefully not breaking the mood here.

Comment: @Yunnosch yes, that is more readable. I was also feeling guilty about the missing semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

If the max column is expected, then I might have a solution:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * 1 3 4 1 
         * 5 7 8 9 
         * 6 1 2 1
         * 
         */


        int[][] arr = {{1, 3, 4, 1}, {5, 7, 8, 9}, {6, 1, 2, 1}};



        int m = arr.length;
        int n = arr[0].length;
        int[] arr2 = new int[n];
        int p = 0;

        int[][] colArray = new int[n][m];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int[] arr_i = new int[m];
            //System.out.println("i = " + i);
            //System.out.println("p = " + p);
            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                arr_i[j] = arr[j][p];
                sum += arr_i[j];
            }
            //System.out.println("Col: " + p + " : " + Arrays.toString(arr_i));
            colArray[i] = arr_i;
            arr2[p] = sum;
            p++;

        }
        System.out.println("Sum: " + Arrays.toString(arr2));
        int k = 0;
        int max = arr2[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (arr2[i] > max) {
                max = arr2[i];
                k = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Column index for max: " + k);
        System.out.println("Column: " + Arrays.toString(colArray[k]));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Sum: [12, 11, 14, 11]
Column index for max: 2
Column: [4, 8, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you find a way to break down your problem into smaller parts, solve each part with a function, then combine everything into a solution.

Example solution below:

```java
public class Main {

  public static long sum(int[] a){
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i : a) {
      sum = sum + i;
    }
    return sum;
  }

  public static int[] withMaxSumOf(int[][] as){
    // keep one sum for each array
    long[] sums = new long[as.length];

    // calculate sums
    for (int i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
      int[] a = as[i];
      sums[i] = sum(a);
    }

    // find the biggest one
    int maxIndex = 0;
    long maxSum = sums[0];
    for (int i=1;i<sums.length;i++){
      if (sums[i] > maxSum){
        maxSum = sums[i];
        maxIndex = i;
      }
    }

    // return array that had biggest sum
    return as[maxIndex];

  }

  public static void main(String[] args){

    int[][] arr= {{1,3,4,1},{5,7,8,9},{6,1,2,1}};

    // find the one with max sum
    int[] max = withMaxSumOf(arr);

    // print it
    for (int i = 0; i < max.length; i++) {
      int x = max[i];
      if (i > 0) System.out.print(", ");
      System.out.print(x);
    }

    System.out.println();

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be your problem:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    if(arr2[i]>max) {
        max=arr2[i];
        i=k;
    }
}
```

I think that i=k really needs to be k=i.

Note also that it's worthwhile using better variable names. index instead of i, for instance. What is k? Call it "indexForHighestSum" or something like that. It doesn't have to be that long, but k is a meaningless name.

Also, you can combine the summation loop with the find-highest loop.

In the end, I might write it like this:

```
public class twoDMax {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[][] arr= { {1,3,4,1}, {5,7,8,9}, {6,1,2,1} };
    int indexForMaxRow = 0;
    int previousMax = 0;

    for(int index = 0; index < 4; ++index) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < 4; ++innerIndex) {
            sum += arr[index][innerIndex];
        }
        if (sum > previousMax) {
            previousMax = sum;
            indexForMaxRow = index;
    }

    System.out.println(indexForMaxRow);
    for(int index = 0; index < 4; ++index) {
        System.out.println(arr[indexForMaxRow][index]);
    }
  }
}
```

I did a few other stylish things. I made use of more obvious variable names. And I am a little nicer about whitespace, which makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MaximumSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] array = { { 2, 8, 7 }, { 7, 1, 3 }, { 1, 9, 5 } };
        int n = array.length;
        int largestSum[] = new int[n];
        int size = largestSum.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            int sum = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {

                sum = sum + array[i][j];
            }

            largestSum[0] = sum;
            Arrays.sort(largestSum);
        }

        System.out.println(largestSum[size - 1]);

    }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main( String args[] ) {
    int[][] arr = { { 1, 3, 4, 1 }, { 5, 7, 8, 9 }, { 6, 1, 2, 1 } };

    int indexOfMaxSum = 0;
    int maxSum = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        int[] innerArr = arr[ i ]; // grab inner array
        int sum = 0; // start sum at 0
        for ( int j : innerArr ) {
            // iterate over each int in array
            sum += j; // add each int to sum
        }
        if ( sum > maxSum ) {
            // if this sum is greater than the old max, store it
            maxSum = sum;
            indexOfMaxSum = i;
        }
    }

    System.out.println( String.format( "Index %d has the highest sum with a sum of %d", indexOfMaxSum, maxSum ) );
    int [] arrayWithLargestSum = arr[indexOfMaxSum]; // return me

}
```

Comment: Code only answers are not at all helpful. Please explain your code.

Comment: Please help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service, by augmenting your code-only answer with some explanation in prose.

Comment: Dude I want to return `{ 5, 7, 8, 9 }` not the summation. Above answer return `29` as answer

Comment: @ShehanLakshmen The answerer has heeded your comment. Please consider deleting it.